# Getting IllegalArgumentException: Invalid SortKey with setSortKeys()

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a bit of trouble dealing with SortKeys. I have a table which uses a custom TableModel. I'm trying to sort the table using SortKeys. For some reason, though, I am getting an error on the line `sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);` Could anyone please help?

My TableModel class is this:

```
class WrongAnswersTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ArrayList<Card> wrongAnswers;

public WrongAnswersTableModel(ArrayList<Card> wrongAnswers) {
    this.wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return wrongAnswers.size();
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    String name = "";

    switch (column) {
    case 0:
        name = "Word";
        break;
    case 1:
        name = "Translation";
        break;
    case 2:
        name = "Times Incorrect";
    }

    return name;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Card card = wrongAnswers.get(rowIndex);
    String value = "";

    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        value = card.getLangFromPrompt();
        break;
    case 1:
        value = card.getLangToPrompt();
        break;
    case 2:
        value = "" + card.getGuessedWrong();
        break;
    }

    return value;
}
}
```

I looked on the rest of StackOverflow and there was something about getColumnCount returning 0, but in my model, getColumnCount definitely returns 3.

I set up my table and the sorter as follows:

```
List<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new SortKey(2, SortOrder.DESCENDING));     
watm = new WrongAnswersTableModel(parent.getTest().getIncorrectCards());
table = new JTable(watm);
table.setEnabled(false);
table.setRowHeight(table.getFont().getSize() + 10);
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
sorter.sort();
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Shouldn't the generic parameter for your TableRowSorter be the `WrongAnswersTableModel` type? Also, I think that you want to return an Integer for the 3rd column data and that you want to override the model's `getColumnClass` method to return `Integer.class` for that column.

Comment: Also, I don't feel it's right your calling `fireTableDataChanged()` **outside** of the model itself. That call should be made internally by your model if the data has changed, and if you can't use another more specific `fireXxxx()` method.

Comment: Note that you don't even want to call `fireTableDataChanged()` since you've not changed the model. Note that sorting the data does not change the model at all, just the display of the data. You will need to convert model to view and visa versa though when interacting with the JTable itself. Other than these bits above, I don't see anything in your code that would cause an error that you describe. I suggest that you post the entire error message and also create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us better understand your problem.

Comment: ... or you could ignore all my comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Really sorry about that, thought I had already replied for some reason :) Anyway, thanks very much for your first bit of advice. That was the problem.